# CakePHP 500 Internal Server Error on Dreamhost

Tags: cakephp, hosting, dreamhost, cakephp-2.1

When i try to host the CakePHP site on my server on DreamHost i get the following error

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@reelstubs.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Link to the URL

> http://reelstubs.com/

Comment: @Jleagle nope we built the site on a local server and shared the code via SVN among the team

Comment: Oops, deleted my first comment. Try looking in /app/tmp/logs. Also, what PHP version are you running?

Comment: locally or on the server ? locally 5.3.5.. server let me check

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues on a MediaTemple (ve) server. Standard, plain install of CakePHP 2.1.3 in the root of my site.

The fix for me was to a RewriteBase line to the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So the line **RewriteBase /** (including the slash at the end) did the trick for me.

!important: Do this for all three .htaccess files, in: **root**, **/app** and **/app/webroot** folders.

Comment: Thank you will try it and revert back.

Comment: @HarshaMV, if you made it work, could, you please tell me how, I have exactly the same problem, but the above answer did not solve it

Comment: @Davo go to control panel and edit the domain. and uncheck Extra Web Security? it will work fine! this will allow u to rewrite correctly using .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

I got this working after fiddling with the options in the Control Panel.

Go to Domains > Edit the Domain you want to install CakePHP in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding 'RewriteBase /' to my htaccess file worked for me. I only edited the file in root.

Comment: if you are using a sub folder use 'RewriteBase /folder_name'